# How to specify an alternative root file system at boot time

Tags: boot, root-filesystem

I had some problem with the default rootfs and always writing out kernel panic. I want to fixed it in the kernel, so I tried many ways to solve this problem. I had base idea to fix , that is before writing out the kernel-panic I try to stop the kernel and I have to choose another rootfs and retry to load chosen rootfs.I have 2 rootfs first is `root=/dev/sda1`the second is `root2=/dev/sdb1`.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the bootloader you use.
If you use GRUB, then press e when the menu shows up and add change the `rootfs` parameter on the `linux` line.

#### Example

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sdb1 quiet splash
```

Comment: it's true but not solving my problem, because I want to do this automatically.I want to extend the kernel source code.Compile this code and i want to use own custom kernel.